# popup window showing a form

Tags: jquery, forms

I'm using google api to develop an app that handles events in a calendar. I have a jquery function that shows a form (function .show()) in the bottom of the browser page. What I would like to do is like what is present in google calendar. When you click on day on the calendar, a popup window showing a form is displayed.
I read that window.open does nearly what I want to do but the problem is that I don't know what to put in the url :

```
window.open('url', 'window name', 'window settings')
```

Actually, the form and my jquery function are in the same file :

```
<div id="addEvent" style="display:none" >
            <form id="addEventForm">

                <label>Titre :</label>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Titre de l'event" id="title" name="title" />


                <label>Date de début :</label>
                <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Date de l'event" id="start_date" name="start_date" />

                <a href="#" onclick="add_event()">Ajouter l'event</a>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Here is how I show the form :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view)
            {     
                 date_format = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(date,"yyyy-MM-dd");
                 display_form(date_format);

            },
         events: 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/myLogin%40gmail.com/public/basic'
        });
    });

 function display_form(s_date)
           {$('#addEvent').show();
            $('#start_date').val(s_date);
           }
```

Comment: You probably want to use a "Modal Dialog" for this instead of a pop-up window. A modal is simply an absolutely-positioned DIV that covers the entire screen with a panel, in which is another DIV containing your form.

Comment: @Diodeus Could you please tell me or show me a tuto that explains how to do?

Comment: Here you go: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Thanks Diodeus. I tried this instead of .show() :   $('#addEvent').dialog("open");   But firebug shows this error : TypeError: $("#addEvent").dialog is not a function

Comment: You'll need to import the jqueryUI plugin first:   
http://jqueryui.com/download

Comment: @user1026361 I already have jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom in the third party folder (I'm using CodeIgniter)